# ¿Como puedo calcular o decidir sobre un String?

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y tengo un problema espero me puedan ayudar.
Tengo que hacer un programa que lee n calificaciones y sacar promedio y ver que calificación es mayor de tal materia. Pero no se como procesar el String para que me de en nombre de la materia que tiene mayor calificación. No se que método utilizar, ayuda.

```
    public void leeprocesa()
    {
        //declara atributos/objetos locales
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=0; //contador de iteracciones

        System.out.println("Ingresa numero de calificaciones:");
        numCal=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        prom=0; //Inicializar acumulador

        for(i=1;i<=numCal;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Ingresa nombre de la materia "+i+":");
            mat1=s.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingresa la calificacion de "+mat1+":");
            calif=Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());
            prom=prom+calif;

            if (califMa < calif)
            {
                califMa=calif;
            }
        }
        prom=prom/numCal;
    }
    //declara metodo de escritura
    public void escribe()
    {   
        System.out.println("Promedio:"+prom);
        System.out.println("La calificacion maxima es "+califMa+" de la materia "+mat1+":");
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear una nueva variable para almacenar el nombre de la materia con mayor valor, ya que `mat1` siempre quedará con el último valor introducido en el bucle.

Sería algo como esto:

```
if (califMa < calif)
{
    califMa=calif;
    matMa=mat1;
}
```

Y al final imprimes ese valor.

Comment: Gracias pero en esa decisión es tipo incompatible y no puede convertir el String a double.

Comment: El nombre de la materia deberia ser String y no hay porque convertir a Double

Comment: qué tipo de datos son tus variables califMa y mat1?

Comment: Segun entiendo califMa es de tipo Double y mat1 es de tipo String, es por eso que el valor de mat1 se guarda en matMa que tambien deberia ser de tipo String